# Pass a JS object to Apex controller as a parameter

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I'm tracking the input fields on an LWC and it works but it's a lot of params  that are being passed to my Apex controller. I have about 20 fields.

I want to pass the parameter as a whole object.  But trying to understand now how to take those inputs, I'll set them as properties of an obj on js side and then pass that obj as a parameter to the Apex controller.

This is being done on a custom object not a standard obj. If someone could give an example of myCustomObject and this scenario I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Can you add whatever code you are already using?

Answer (score 1):

Just match up the field names, and pass that to Apex.

## Apex

```
@AuraEnabled public static void method(MyCustomObject__c record) {
  // ...
}
```

## JavaScript

```js
let record = { 
  sobjectType: 'MyCustomObject__c', // tells Apex sObject type
  Name: 'Demo', 
  Field1__c: 'Hello', // Example text field
  Field2__c: true, // Example checkbox field
  Field3__c: 42.0 // Example number field
};
method({record}).then((result) => {
  // Handle success
}).catch((error) => {
  // Handle error
});
```